# Reading the Number Of Slice from DICOM Header of a MRI 2D Multi-slice

Tags: c++, dicom

I am working on reading a MRI 2D multi-slice, and looking for the number of slice it has.

But unfortunately, there is no slice count in the DICOM header. I would like to ask why and how can I get the slice count rather than just reading the DICOM header directly. Can I calculate the slice count from any physical value of the slice?

I have SiemensTag0029_1020.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you dealing with newer multi-frame Enhanced MR Image (1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4.1) or older single frame MR Image (1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4)? With multi-frame DICOM file, you can look-up Number Of Frames (0028,0008) tags.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with MR Image Storage instances, you can simply order all the instances according to there IPP (Image Position Patient) and IOP (Image Orientation Patient) attributes. There is a well known algorithm that compute the distances along the normal of each instances and order those accordingly. It has proven to be very reliable. See for example: [gdcm::IPPSorter](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1IPPSorter.html#_details)